# Find the Distance Point to Line with Point on Line and Direction Vector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

We are given two Vector3's for the Line; Vector3 Point on the Line; Vector3 Direction along the line.

We are also given the certain point which is the point outside the line.

So how am i supposed to find the shortest distance from the point outside the line to the line ? I guess assuming the line is infinitely long

This is what i have for a example like this:
x, y, z

Vector3 Pt_on_ln = 2, 2, 3
Vector3 Ln_dir = 5, 7, 1
Vector3 Pt = 3, 2, 1

Vector3 vect_a = Pt - Pt_on_ln
Vector3 vect_b = Pt - Ln_dir
Vector3 vect_c = Ln_dir - Pt_on_ln

Cross Product
Vector3 cross_a = vect_a x vect_b

Magnitude cross_a / Magnitude vect_c

I dont know if this is correct or not
I have no idea of how to check my answer. I cant find any calculators online.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `Vector3`?

Comment: Sorry if it confused you. But i only included it there it show that its a Vector3 variable. Including x , y and z values.

Comment: @JekasG You should clarify things. It seems the variable is used for different things: once a point, once a vector etc. You should use different names for the different variables ($A$, $B$ etc for instance) and each of this variable can have $x,y,z$ components (labelled $x_A$ for instance).

Answer (score 0):

**Sketch:**

Let $A$ be the point on line $\ell$, $u$ its directing vector and $M$ the point outside the line. You have to find  the orthogonal projection $H$ of $M$ on $\ell$. It is the point on $\ell$, such that the inner product $\langle H-M,u\rangle=0$, i. e.
$$\langle A+tu -M,u\rangle=0\iff \langle M -A,u\rangle=t\mkern1.5mu\lVert u\rVert^2. $$
Thus $H$ is the point $\,A+\dfrac{\langle M -A,u\rangle}{\lVert u\rVert^2}\,u$ and the distance is
$$ \lVert H-M\rVert=\Biggl\lVert A-M+\frac{\langle M -A,u\rangle}{\lVert u\rVert^2}\,u\,\Biggr\rVert$$

Comment: Do you know if there is any online calculator for this ? So i can check if my answer is correct ? Or use my example values from my question ?

Comment: Does the ',' represent cross product ?

Comment: For a calculator, I don't know.  You should find $\, t=\frac1{25}$. `< , >` represents the inner (dot) product.

Comment: What is the value of u ?

Comment: $u$ is the directing vector of $\ell$: $\,(5,7,1)$.